# SSH conection problem after write an invalid alias

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, ssh, alias

I've made a new alias in the remote machine `/.bashrc`, since I did it and I close the session I just can't log in again using the shh protocol. As you can see in the code, when I try to log in, the machine prompts a error with the alias, it doesn't let you to type anything and few minutes later the connection is closed.

```
name@user2:~$ ssh remotename@adress.com
remotename@adress.com password: 
/home/user/.bashrc: line 18: alias: /data/user/remotename/software/env-shell.sh: not found

Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65432
```

I would like to know if there is a solution with no direct access to the remote machine?

Pd: I can't delete the alias anymore and I can't be 100% sure that the problem is due to the alias.

Comment: What does this show? less /etc/ssh/sshd_config Is the new alias on that list?
Try this ssh remotename@adress.com -v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is within your ~/.bashrc file, then any of the following should work:

1. open an interactive bash shell in place of the default login shell, but skip the rc files

   ```
   ssh -t remotename@adress.com 'bash --norc'
   ```
2. open a different interactive shell that doesn't read ~/.bashrc

   ```
   ssh -t remotename@adress.com '/bin/sh'
   ```
3. open your remote user's ~/.bashrc for editing directly so that you can fix it

   ```
   ssh -t remotename@adress.com 'nano ~/.bashrc'
   ```

The `-t` requests allocation of a tty so that you can execute interactive commands without invoking the usual login shell.

Comment: I've just tried the third one, deleted the alias and now everything works perfectly! Many thanks!! :)